# Cannot clear people picker through Javascript

Tags: javascript, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

I've generated a people picker and I'm trying to clear it when i reset the form but it keeps giving me this error:

```
        clear: pickerId => {
            var picker =
                SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerId];
            var users = picker.GetAllUserInfo();

            if (_.isEmpty(users)) return false;

            _.map(users, user => {
                picker.DeleteProcessedUser(user);
            });

            console.log("Emptied picker ", pickerId);
        },
```

[image]